# (iOS Swift) How to set local notification sound if sound file is over 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I have a sound file that is over 30 seconds. I want to play sound in local notification and the sound should come from that sound file. I am aware of the 30 second limit but what can I do so that the local notification plays the first 30 seconds of that sound file rather than returning nil and playing default sound (due to it being > 30 seconds)?

Comment: Have you considered trimming the file down?

Comment: It's basically an alarm app. If the app is still running then I want the sound to play as long as the file. But due to limitation in local notification if the app is in background then that same sound should be played in (first) 30 seconds. Also files are in mp3 mode.

Comment: just split it into 2 ios sound file (not mp3), and schedule to call them with 30s interval

Comment: That would take up too much memory....

Comment: split it outside of app! use first part in first alarm and after 30s interval play second part. It will be weird if user have disabled first alarm in 5th sec. Anyway thig for it just use 30 s sound.